# Backup in Linux with resume support only the latest one

Tags: rsync

We have a backup server in a remote location with low bandwidth. We send data to that server in a regular basis from our Datacenter.
The file size of each day backup is around 100 GB. We would like to keep there last 3 days back that is 3 file.

I am trying to make a cronjob to send the last created file everyday.

Till now I am trying with rsync. Can anyone suggest any other tool to do this? Have to keep in mind that the BW is low and connection might be interrupted but the transmission should be completed.

If I want to use rsync how could I automatically choose the last created 1 file.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do would be using `duplicity`, it is a backup tool which manages full and incremental backups and has useful functions such as `--full-if-older-than <time>` or `remove-older-than <time>`.

Considering your BW problems, I would personally use `rsync`, rsync was made to synchronise folders so it would prevent you to download files you already have. You could use a shell script to create archives of the folder created with rsync and erase older archives.

Comment: In the main server we keep backup of more than 3 days, but in remote we want to keep only latest 3 files. Is it possible by `--full-if-older-than <time>` or `remove-older-than <time>`.


We made a script with 'FTP' and 'PUT', that is working fine. Does ftp will work with the connection interruption?


Also by `rsync` I made it successful `rsync -avz -e ssh `ls -tp *.dmp | grep -v / | head -n 3` root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/u01/backup/ --progress --include '*.dmp' --exclude '*' --ignore-existing`

Comment: Congratulation ;) I don't really know about ftp. `rsync` can continue an interrupted backup without problem.